# Numbering the output of grep

Tags: shell, grep

When we're filtering the output with grep, is there any way we can get line numbered output, like we get with `cat -n`?
I'm not asking for the `grep -n` option which shows the line number of the match in the file.

The scenario I want to use it in is that when I download multiple files using aria2, I usually filter the output with keyword NOTICE which gives me some output every time a file download is completed. But I have actually no way of knowing how many files have been downloaded.

Comment: If you can afford losing grep colours then becomes as easy as piping it.

Comment: Losing colors is fine but I actually wanted the filtered output to be line-numbered. Using nl solves this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like

```
grep PATTERN FILE | nl
```

or

```
grep PATTERN FILE | wc -l
```

The first one will number the filtered lines. The second one will count them all.

Comment: Thanks for this, **nl** works. I also had to add --line-buffered to grep since I was filtering out data from a continuous stream.